# Unable to write the dataframe to target sftp server using spark-sftp api

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-sftp

I am trying to do sftp and writing the dataframe from the spark-cluster to the target sftp server.

The code works fine with spark-shell but when I try it using scala code deploying my jar it fails with the below error:

```
*Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=abcuser, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x*
```

I tried using the below in spark-shell and its working :

```
    spark2-shell --queue xyz --packages com.springml:spark-sftp_2.11:1.1.3

    val df = sparksession.sql(s"select * from db.table")

    df.write.format("com.springml.spark.sftp").option("host", "hostname").option("username", "username").option("password", "abc").option("port","22").option("fileType", "csv").option("delimiter", "|").option("header","true").save("/Download/file.txt")
```

But fails in my scala code . Below is my program:

```
    import com.springml.spark.sftp._

    val df = sparksession.sql(s"select * from db.table")

    df.write.format("com.springml.spark.sftp")
       .option("host", "hostname")
       .option("username", "username")
       .option("password", "abc")
       .option("port","22")
       .option("fileType", "csv")
       .option("delimiter", "|")
       .option("header","false")
       .save("sftp_directory")
```

Can someone let me know the error or something I am missing .

Below is my spark-submit command in which I added all the required jars.All the 3 jars have been added using the option --jar.

```
 kinit -kt abcuser.keytab -V abcuser
 spark2-submit --class com.sample.Program1 \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --queue queuename \
  --files sample.conf \
  --executor-memory 25G \
  --driver-memory 20G \
  --executor-cores 5 \
  --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
  --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=100 \
  --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4096 \
  --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=2 \
  --conf spark.network.timeout=1500 \
  --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=1500  \
  --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=2000  \
  --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=25G \
  --conf spark.shuffle.blockTransferService=nio \
  --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs \
  --jars hdfs://devnameservice/user/abcuser/jsch-0.1.53.jar,
   hdfs://devnameservice/user/abcuser/sftp.client1.0.3.jar,
   hdfs://devnameservice/user/abcuser/spark-sftp_2.11-1.1.0.jar \
   --packages com.springml:spark-sftp_2.11:1.1.3 \
    project-core.jar sample.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Following spark documentation:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

> Note: When running Spark on YARN in cluster mode, environment
>   variables need to be set using the
>   spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName] property in your
>   conf/spark-defaults.conf file. Environment variables that are set in
>   spark-env.sh will not be reflected in the YARN Application Master
>   process in cluster mode. See the YARN-related Spark Properties for
>   more information.

So either you modify your spark-defaults.conf, or you can pass it as a configuration of your spark-submit.

Since it's a permission error, you can add this to your spark-submit configuration:

`./bin/spark-submit 
--name "My app" 
--master local[4]`

**--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs**

`myApp.jar`

Comment: I tried the below conf parameter  but still its giving the same error.
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs



I have attached the spark-submit command I am using in the code . Please suggest.

Comment: Could you add some logging, and log:

`sparksession.sparkContext.getConf.getAll`, to see if the config parameter is taken into account ?

Comment: You can try this:

`sparksession.sparkContext.conf.set("spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hdfs")`

Comment: Yes I checked printing the logs after setting the conf property  . I can see that this property is successfully set . But still the error remains the same.

Comment: Could you show the value of `HADOOP_USER_NAME` in conf/spark-defaults.conf please ?

Comment: I have printed the values using below code:
         sparksession.sparkContext.getConf.getAll.foreach(x => {
          println(s"The key = ${x._1} and the value = ${x._2}")
           })

And below are some of values printed:
       The key = spark.app.name and the value = abc
       The key = spark.master and the value = yarn
       The key = spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_USER_NAME and the 
        value = hdfs

Comment: One more thing to add , my target ftp location is windows directory and not  hdfs , do you think this api works this way.

Comment: Since it's working using spark2-shell, may be you can start by printing the config which work, and see the difference. I will check if it works that way using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create user directory in HDFS corresponding to your UNIX username used to submit the job

```
for UNAME in abcuser; do
  hdfs dfs -test -e /user/$UNAME 
  if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]
  then 
    hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/$UNAME || error=0
    hdfs dfs -chmod 777 /user/$UNAME || error=0
    hdfs dfs -chown $UNAME /user/$UNAME || error=0
  fi
done
```

You can also do spark submit using different username by passing parameter:

```
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_USER_NAME=hadoop
```